# Проблема с сравнением имени авторизованного пользователя и поля ForeignKey (Django) в шаблонизаторе

Tags: python, html, django

Необходимо сравнить имя авторизованного пользователя и поле ForeignKey
Если имя схоже с полем ForeignKey то вывести некую запись
как понимаю проблема заключается в том что я сравниваю две переменных разных типов. Пытался перевести переменные через фильтр |string шаблонизатора jinja, но не помогло.
Если отдельно выводить переменные **user.get_username** и **el.author** ,то на сайте они отображаются корректно в текстовом формате.
Подскажите в чем заключается моя ошибка при сравнении этих двух переменных

```
#Kabinet.html
{% extends 'main/layout.html' %}

{% block title %}Личный кабинет{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="features">
        <h1>Личный кабинет</h1>
        {% if orders %}
            {% for el in orders %}
                {% if user.get_username == el.author %}
                    <div class="alert alert-warning">
                        <h3>Заказ № {{ el }}</h3>
                    </div>
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
        {% else %}
            <p>На данный момент заказов нет</p>
        {% endif %}
        <a href="{% url 'exit' %}"><button class="btn btn-info">Выйти из аккаунта</button></a>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

```
#models.py
from django.db import models

class Order(models.Model):
    number = models.CharField('Номер телефона', max_length=15)
    soc = models.CharField('Социальная сеть', max_length=250)
    full_text = models.TextField('Описание заказа')
    author = models.ForeignKey( 'auth.User',on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.number

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return f'/orders/{self.id}'

    class Meta:
        verbose_name='Заказ'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Заказы'
```

```
#views.py
def kabinet(request):
    orders=Order.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'main/kabinet.html',{'orders':orders})
```

Comment: Во-первых, это не jinja

Comment: Во-вторых, если вы у user вызываете get_username, то значит и у el.author тоже вызывайте get_username. Или наоборот, если вы у el.author не вызываете get_username, то значит и у user его тоже не надо вызывать

Comment: Всё, понял. Всё заработало, спасибо большое !